# Add Custom Headers using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, http-headers

I am not really sure what type of headers these highlighted values are, but how should I add them using HttpWebRequest?

[image: HTTP Header]

Is the highlighted part considered body of the http request or header data? In other words, which way is correct?

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("/securecontrol/reset/passwordreset");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic asdadsasdas8586");
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Host = "www.xxxxxxxxxx.com";
request.Method = "POST";
request.Proxy = null;
request.Headers.Add("&command=requestnewpassword");
request.Headers.Add("&application=netconnect");
```

But should I use the following instead to build the Http Request above?

```
string reqString = "&command=requestnewpassword&application=netconnect";
byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqString);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("/securecontrol/reset/passwordreset");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic ashAHasd87asdHasdas");
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = requestData.Length;
request.Proxy = null;
request.Host = "www.xxxxxxxxxx.com";
request.Method = "POST";

using (Stream st = request.GetRequestStream())
st.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);
```

Comment: Your first code snippet should work fine, but to verify that the data is in fact in the header, did you try looking at the packet in Wireshark or something similar?  In Wireshark, you can right-click a packet, select to open it in a new window, then expand the "Hypertext Transfer Protocol" section.

Comment: @M. Babcock: They are not the same, I changed the values in the code.

Comment: @Lander : I am working with a very secure server and the actual code is so big and it seems it takes time to test it unfortunately :/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IMHO it is considered as malformed header data.

You actually want to send those name value pairs as  the request content (this is the way POST works) **and not as headers**.

The second way is true.

Comment: OK thanks I agree with you I just wanted to make sure I am doing fine.

Comment: While this might not be best practice, sending headers in an HTTP request is sometimes necessary, particularly when using certain APIs.

Answer (score 23):

A simple method of creating the service, adding headers and reading the JSON response,

```
private static void WebRequest()
{
    const string WEBSERVICE_URL = "<<Web Service URL>>";
    try
    {
        var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(WEBSERVICE_URL);
        if (webRequest != null)
        {
            webRequest.Method = "GET";
            webRequest.Timeout = 20000;
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic dcmGV25hZFzc3VudDM6cGzdCdvQ=");
            using (System.IO.Stream s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
                {
                    var jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Response: {0}", jsonResponse));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I needed for my header. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help @Vippy

Comment: This works great but you in my case I needed to do the following: myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username + ":" + password")));