# How to get text in stream from WebRequest?

Tags: c#, webrequest

So, here's a scenario that I made up, in which I am making my own web browser and I want to make sure I'm sending correct POST text to web server.

For that to be achieved, I need to get the POST text that WebRequest creates for me before I invoke `GetResponseStream()`.

I tried to read through the stream from `WebRequest.GetRequestStream()`, but I assume that isn't a way to do that.

I do NOT want plain HTML text responsed from web server.
The POST text that I need to gain must look like something like this as follows :

```
POST http://www.some_web_server.com/default.aspx HTTP/1.1 
Cache-Control : max-age=0 Connection : keep-alive .....
```

Thanks in advance.

**[UPDATE]**

It's clear that I already have all fomulated *request*(POST) text in my WebRequest instance.

Is there any way conveniently to just get the whole plain text from it, rather than using separated get properties such as `ContentType` or `Headers`?

(Because I am lazy to 'assemble' all the headers that I specified into the whole complete POST text, which web server will eventually see.)

```
// This might be a very poor code to approach.

public void Show_Full_POST_Text(WebRequest req)
{
    // For example.
    String strRawText = req.GetRequestLiteral();

    // Your POST text looks like this!
    ShowToUser(strRawText);
}

public void Foo()
{
    // ...

    Show_Full_POST_Text(req);
    var ResponseStream = req.GetResponseStream();

    // Continue.
}
```

Comment: Why do you want the **response**?

Comment: @Greg I want the request. Thanks.

Comment: You would have all of that information when you formulate your *request*, via headers, content, body, type, and etc. countless other options. So why do you need it, you should already know it.

Comment: @Gred You're 100% right. I just think that if I can easily get the whole plain POST text without any attempts to paste(or 'assemble') my headers, content, body, and everythig, it'll be much convenient for me to be parsing the POST text.

Comment: I'm not sure your intention, but couldn't you just as easily read the response for success.  Since your going to be creating a request `var request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.url.com") as HttpWebRequest;`  So you can see the URL, but read the response for when it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your saying that you don't want to get some headers via the request properties e.g "request.ContentType" and other via the header collection, then you can just use the header collection as it already contains the key for ContentType.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "image/png";

            Console.WriteLine(GetRequestAsString(request));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static string GetRequestAsString(HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            string str = request.Method + " " + request.RequestUri + " HTTP/" + request.ProtocolVersion + Environment.NewLine;
            string[] headerKeys = request.Headers.AllKeys;

            foreach (string key in headerKeys)
            {
                str += key + ":" + request.Headers[key];
            }

            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that there is no method supported in the exact way I wanted it to be. However surely knowing that there isn't from you also helped me a lot. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague, however, I believe what you're looking for is including the headers within the Webrequest. [The MSDN has a good example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). See below:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (args[0]);

    // Set some reasonable limits on resources used by this request
    request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
    request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4; //This sets the max headers coming back to your response.
    // Set credentials to use for this request.
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();

    Console.WriteLine ("Content length is {0}", response.ContentLength);
    Console.WriteLine ("Content type is {0}", response.ContentType);

    // Get the stream associated with the response.
    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream ();

    // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

    Console.WriteLine ("Response stream received.");
    Console.WriteLine (readStream.ReadToEnd ());
    response.Close ();
    readStream.Close ();
}
```

Comment: I think hes after the headers for the request not the response.

Comment: If he's after the headers in the request, that doesn't make much sense. The user specifies what the headers need to be, not get them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842539/add-custom-headers-using-httpwebrequest