# Is it possible to set header in URL for WebView in Xamarin Forms.

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms

I want to send a pair of string ex. "Token" = "XSFFDFDGF32234234" to server.

Comment: Which WebSocket are you using?

Comment: It a normal HTTP request ex. http://192.168.1.123/testserver/getdata. I have to send "Token" as a http header.

Comment: Take a look at `HttpWebRequest`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx 

Example can be found in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842539/add-custom-headers-using-httpwebrequest

It's hard to provide an answer because you give no information at all about what you tried, how you want to achieve it, what you are using etc.